# Problem with request.request_uri when forwarding from AJAX partial - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial

In my Rails logging in functionality I use

```
session[:return_to] = request.request_uri
```

and then in the logging functionality I use:

```
redirect_to session[:return_to]
```

Which works fine except when I render a partial with AJAX. What happens is that the request.uri is for the AJAX request which screws up and doesn't render what's expected.

You know how I can go around this?

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you want:

```
redirect_to :back
```

Comment: That didn't work! it actually kept the user at the login page

Answer (score 0):

`request.request_uri` will indeed be for the AJAX URI. The only solution I've found is to make your AJAX requests (or at least, the ones that may cause a redirect to the login page) include the URI of the whole page, e.g.

```
form_remote_for ... do |f|
    hidden_field_tag :this_page, request.request_uri
    # only works if this view itself is not loaded over AJAX!
```

or for a more universal approach:

```
form_remote_for :html => {:onsubmit => '$("this_page").value = window.location'}, ... do |f|
    hidden_field_tag :this_page, request.request_uri
    # non-JS clients just end up with the value given here
```

Combine either of these with

```
# in the login action
session[:return_to] = params[:this_page]
```